# What is an adjective to describe something that caused a problem?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I have an error message that describes the cause for a problem/crash in my application. What is an adjective I can use to refer to that error message?

I would like to say something like this:

> This is the [adjective] error:

To mean this:

> This is the error that caused the crash:

Is there a good adjective that clearly indicates that the noun it is describing to is the cause of the problem the speaker/writer is referring to?

Comment: You’ve already said that it caused the crash. Why would you need to say it again?  “This is the crash-causing error that caused the crash” seems needlessly repetitive and redundant.  I suppose you could say *original error* or *originating error*, but I still think “that caused the crash” has enough info in it.

Comment: @tchrist I'm not looking for a way to say it again, but a different way to say it (instead of saying that it caused the problem) that is simpler and more clear, if such a way exists. I wouldn't say both ways at the same time.

Comment: Problematic, troublesome?

Comment: OP's example reads to me like a request for an adjective suitable for describing an error *message*, which seems a bit pointless. What needs to be looked at isn't the error message, it's [***the offending code***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+offending+code%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the adjective *[causative](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/causative)*.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **decisive**. According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decisive),

> causing something to end in a particular way : determining what the result of something will be

Similarly, **critical**. Also from [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/critical)

> crucial, decisive: *a critical test*

Answer (score 1):

> I might say one of these:
>
> - "This is the lethal error."
> - "Here is the critical error."
> - "Here is the fatal error."

Answer (score 0):

**Problematic**

From Google:

> constituting or presenting a problem or difficulty.

In the context of "Show me the problem"

On could answer:

> This is the problematic error:

Answer (score 0):

I know, not an adjective, but it's just too common not to mention.

You are looking for the [**root cause**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/root-cause?q=root+cause).

Since you mention your app, have a look at the wikipedia article about [root cause analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_cause_analysis). It is a very commonly used word in the IT industry to indicate the - well - root cause that actually caused your problem.